# Non-deterministic errors with python client on streaming inserts

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with the following schema:

```
    [
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "LOTRANS",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "FIRMWARE",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "MBATTCHG",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "BATTV",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "MINTIMEL",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "STARTTIME",
        "type": "DATETIME"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "NOMBATTV",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "DATE",
        "type": "DATETIME"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "MODEL",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "HITRANS",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "TIMELEFT",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "BCHARGE",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "XONBATT",
        "type": "DATETIME"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "TONBATT",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "LINEV",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "XOFFBATT",
        "type": "DATETIME"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "ALARMDEL",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "STATUS",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "CUMONBATT",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "CABLE",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "UPSMODE",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "LASTXFER",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "DRIVER",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "VERSION",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "LOADPCT",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "NOMINV",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "ENDAPC",
        "type": "DATETIME"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "SERIALNO",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "HOSTNAME",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "UPSNAME",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "NUMXFERS",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "SENSE",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "APC",
        "type": "STRING"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "MAXTIME",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "BATTDATE",
        "type": "DATE"
    },
    {
        "mode": "REQUIRED",
        "name": "STATFLAG",
        "type": "INTEGER"
    }
]
```

An example of the data row is as follows:

```
{
    "ALARMDEL": "No alarm",
    "APC": "001,035,0928",
    "BATTDATE": "2016-12-02",
    "BATTV": "13.7",
    "BCHARGE": "100.0",
    "CABLE": "USB Cable",
    "CUMONBATT": "2758",
    "DATE": "2017-07-04T20:20:26",
    "DRIVER": "USB UPS Driver",
    "ENDAPC": "2017-07-04T20:20:35",
    "FIRMWARE": "904.W1 .D USB FW:W1",
    "HITRANS": "139.0",
    "HOSTNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "LASTXFER": "Unacceptable line voltage changes",
    "LINEV": "120.0",
    "LOADPCT": "0.0",
    "LOTRANS": "92.0",
    "MAXTIME": "0",
    "MBATTCHG": "5",
    "MINTIMEL": "3",
    "MODEL": "Back-UPS ES 550G",
    "NOMBATTV": "12.0",
    "NOMINV": "120",
    "NUMXFERS": "188",
    "SENSE": "Medium",
    "SERIALNO": "REDACTED",
    "STARTTIME": "2017-05-23T13:27:07",
    "STATFLAG": "0x05000008",
    "STATUS": "ONLINE",
    "TIMELEFT": "335.8",
    "TONBATT": "0",
    "UPSMODE": "Stand Alone",
    "UPSNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "VERSION": "3.14.12 (29 March 2014) debian",
    "XOFFBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:55",
    "XONBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:53"
}
```

I tried following the [example code](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery-stream-data-python), but whenever I try to insert_data with the above dictionary using the python client I get non-deterministic errors such as

```
[{'index': 0, 'errors': [{u'debugInfo': u'generic::invalid_argument: Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):MBATTCHG', u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):MBATTCHG', u'location': u'mbattchg'}]}]
```

But the error changes on every attempted insert. What are ways to help debug why the errors are not deterministic, and why the converted values tend to be the keys of the dictionary instead of the values?

EDIT

Modified the event to the following, still getting errors

```
{
    "ALARMDEL": "No alarm",
    "APC": "001,035,0928",
    "BATTDATE": "2016-12-02",
    "BATTV": 13.7,
    "BCHARGE": 100.0,
    "CABLE": "USB Cable",
    "CUMONBATT": 2758,
    "DATE": "2017-07-05T02:41:00",
    "DRIVER": "USB UPS Driver",
    "ENDAPC": "2017-07-05T02:41:07",
    "FIRMWARE": "904.W1 .D USB FW:W1",
    "HITRANS": 139.0,
    "HOSTNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "LASTXFER": "Unacceptable line voltage changes",
    "LINEV": 123.0,
    "LOADPCT": 0.0,
    "LOTRANS": 92.0,
    "MAXTIME": 0,
    "MBATTCHG": 5,
    "MINTIMEL": 3.0,
    "MODEL": "Back-UPS ES 550G",
    "NOMBATTV": 12.0,
    "NOMINV": 120.0,
    "NUMXFERS": "188",
    "SENSE": "Medium",
    "SERIALNO": "REDACTED",
    "STARTTIME": "2017-05-23T13:27:07",
    "STATFLAG": 83886088,
    "STATUS": "ONLINE",
    "TIMELEFT": 335.8,
    "TONBATT": 0,
    "UPSMODE": "Stand Alone",
    "UPSNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "VERSION": "3.14.12 (29 March 2014) debian",
    "XOFFBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:55",
    "XONBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:53"
}
```

I tried to post the same object 2 different times and ended up with the following error messages (different each time)

```
[{'index': 0, 'errors': [{u'debugInfo': u'generic::invalid_argument: Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):CUMONBATT', u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):CUMONBATT', u'location': u'cumonbatt'}]}]
[{'index': 0, 'errors': [{u'debugInfo': u'generic::out_of_range: Invalid datetime string "LOADPCT"', u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Invalid datetime string "LOADPCT"', u'location': u'endapc'}]}]
```

EDIT 2:

Fixed by using the returned schema for the table to construct an array instead of passing in an object

```
e = []
for schema_item in table._schema:
    e.append(d[schema_item.name])

rows = [e]
```

Comment: Try printing the row before inserting it (or printing it only when there is an error). What do you see?

Comment: @ElliottBrossard it is a python object. json.dumps on the object gives the simple maps above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The row you used as example isn't in accordance with your schema indeed. It should be like:

```
{
    "ALARMDEL": "No alarm",
    "APC": "001,035,0928",
    "BATTDATE": "2016-12-02",
    "BATTV": 13.7,
    "BCHARGE": 100.0,
    "CABLE": "USB Cable",
    "CUMONBATT": 2758,
    "DATE": "2017-07-04T20:20:26",
    "DRIVER": "USB UPS Driver",
    "ENDAPC": "2017-07-04T20:20:35",
    "FIRMWARE": "904.W1 .D USB FW:W1",
    "HITRANS": 139.0,
    "HOSTNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "LASTXFER": "Unacceptable line voltage changes",
    "LINEV": 120.0,
    "LOADPCT": 0.0,
    "LOTRANS": 92.0,
    "MAXTIME": 0,
    "MBATTCHG": 5,
    "MINTIMEL": 3,
    "MODEL": "Back-UPS ES 550G",
    "NOMBATTV": 12.0,
    "NOMINV": 120,
    "NUMXFERS": 188,
    "SENSE": "Medium",
    "SERIALNO": "REDACTED",
    "STARTTIME": "2017-05-23T13:27:07",
    "STATFLAG": "0x05000008",
    "STATUS": "ONLINE",
    "TIMELEFT": 335.8,
    "TONBATT": 0,
    "UPSMODE": "Stand Alone",
    "UPSNAME": "raspberrypi-master",
    "VERSION": "3.14.12 (29 March 2014) debian",
    "XOFFBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:55",
    "XONBATT": "2017-07-04T03:55:53"
}
```

Notice that `FLOATS` should be represented as a `FLOAT` number, not as a `STRING` (19.2 instead of "19.2" for instance).

One problem that would remain is the field `STATFLAG`, you defined it as an INTEGER but it has the character "x", maybe you'll have to change its type to be a `STRING`.

[EDIT]:

As for the python code, just remember that you should use the method `insert_data` from the `Table` class and for the `rows` input you should have a list with tuples for each row being insert, for instance:

```
rows=[(92.0, '904.W1 .D USB FW:W1', 5, 13.7, 3, '2017-05-23T13:27:07', 12.0, '2017-07-04T20:20:26', 'Back-UPS ES 550G', 139.0, 335.8, 100.0, '2017-07-4T03:55:53', 0, 120.0, '2017-07-04T03:55:55', 'No alarm', 'ONLINE', 758, 'USB Cable', 'Stand Alone', 'Unacceptable line voltage changes', 'USB UPS river', '3.14.12 (29 March 2014) debian', 0.0, 120, '2017-07-4T20:20:35', 'REDACTED', 'raspberrypi-master', 'raspberrypi-master', 88, 'Medium', '001,035,0928', 0, '2016-12-02', 5000008)]
table.insert_data(rows)
```

Comment: This did not work. Updated comment with example with the suggested modifications.

Comment: If you try to stream just this updated row for testing purpose, does it work?

Comment: Unfortunately no: `[{'index': 0, 'errors': [{u'debugInfo': u'generic::invalid_argument: Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):ENDAPC', u'reason': u'invalid', u'message': u'Cannot convert value to integer (bad value):ENDAPC', u'location': u'cumonbatt'}]}]`

Comment: I feel like `cumonbatt` not being `ENDAPC` should be important, but I don't know enough about the python client to know why it is trying to parse dictionary keys as values.

Comment: do you mind posting what is the code you are using to run this stream?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/drcrallen/7ce5fb627610349c9a9c5296ea91b244 reproduces the error

Comment: please check the edit I made to my post. Notice you must send a `tuple` with values and not a `dict` to `insert_data`. I created a table like yours here and I've already streamed 1k rows with no errors so far.

Comment: Ended up making arrays instead of dictionaries it seems to work! thanks!